# How to Concatenate multiple repetitive nodes into a single node - BizTalk

Tags: dictionary, concatenation, biztalk, biztalk-mapper

I have something like this in an input XML

```
  <OrderText>
    <text_type>0012</text_type>
    <text_content>Text1</text_content>
  </OrderText>
  <OrderText>
    <text_type>ZT03</text_type>
    <text_content>Text2</text_content>
  </OrderText>
```

The above data I need to map after concatenating as the below schema

```
<Order>
    <Note>0012:Text1#ZT03:Text2</Note>
</Order>
```

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that your input actually has a Root node, as otherwise it is not valid XML.

```
<Root>
 <OrderText>
    <text_type>0012</text_type>
    <text_content>Text1</text_content>
  </OrderText>
  <OrderText>
    <text_type>ZT03</text_type>
    <text_content>Text2</text_content>
  </OrderText>
</Root>
```

Then all you need is a map like this

[image: Map Image]

With a String Concatenate functoid with

```
Input[0] = text_type
Input[1] = :
Input[2] = text_content
Input[3] = #
```

That goes into a Cumulative Concatenate

This will give you an output of

```
<Order>
  <Note>0012:Text1#ZT03:Text2#</Note> 
</Order>
```

Note: There is a extra # at the end, but you could use some more functoids to trim that off if needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Value-Mapping Flattening](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/value-mapping-flattening-functoid) functoid in a map, then feed the result of each into a Concatenate functoid to generate the result string. The map can be executed on a port or in an orchestration.

Comment: This is a very helpful in getting specific values from a repeating record as input to a script functoid.